# GTK and Qt apps seem to interpret XCompose differently

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, gtk, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. By default, typing something like <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> produces `²`, which I don't want: I want it to be `^2`. I found out that to accomplish that, one has to set `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` and `QT_IM_MODULE=xim` to use XIM, and then a custom `.XCompose` file can be set up in the home directory. In my case, I replaced the old rule

`<dead_circumflex> <2> : "²"   twosuperior # SUPERSCRIPT TWO`

with

`<dead_circumflex> <2> : "^2"   twosuperior # SUPERSCRIPT TWO`

This seems to work fine with GTK apps (like Firefox or Gedit, or Chrome, which I don't think actually uses GTK) but not with QT (I've tested TeXStudio and Mathematica): typing <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> just produces `^`.

Earlier, `QT_IM_MODULE` was not set to `xim` and QT programs were producing the default `²`, so clearly `.XCompose` is being read now; is it possible that QT interprets the rule differently somehow?

Comment: In "(I've tested TeXStudio and Mathematica): typing ^+2 just produces ^." shouldn't that be "... just produces `^2.`"?

Comment: @DKBose No, producing `^2` would be the intended behavior, but I only get `^`.

Comment: I have Kubuntu 18.04 and typed `^+2` in Kate and got `^2` not `²` nor just `^`. Hence my query.

Comment: If `^` is a dead key, do you not have to type something like `^^` to get a `^`? I am not sure as I don't use dead-keys. I do know that you can't just type that character by pressing the key.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, but by "typing `^`" I mean pressing the `^` key, not producing the `^` character.

Comment: @Javier yes I was using typing in the same way ( to mean pressing the key). So let me ask again, this time being more clear. Do you not have to press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> to get a `^`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm not sure I understand your question. To get a displayed ^ character I press `^^` (or `^`+space), but to get something like â I press `^a`.

Comment: You just answered it. So to get `^2` you press `^^2` and to get `²` you press `^2`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor For letters everything is good, but I don't want numbers to be superscripted, that's the point. I want `^a` to be â but `^2` to be ^2.

Comment: Add that last comment to the question, it seems like useful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the dead key feature of `^` key, you can remap the key to a regular `^` with `xmodmap`. Check which keycode is assigned to the key using `xev` and use something like `xmodmap -e 'keycode 15 = asciicircum'`.

Comment: This would work, but I would prefer a solution that still lets me use `^` as a dead key.